# PHP - Ban IP's Using Array From MySQL?

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to have a basic script that will just die at the top of the page if the users IP is in the database of banned IP's. I have a script that so far will insert an IP with an auto incrementing ID, and the IP. I am using the PDO library, how would I take the returned array from the database and check if in_array?

Here is how I'm returning my database info.

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        id, 
        ip
    FROM banned 
"; 

try 
{ 

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 
} 
catch(PDOException $ex) 
{ 

    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 


$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Then here is just a quick script I wrote to just die at the top of the page and redirect.

```
if(in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], $row["ip"])) 
{ 
header("Location: banned.php")
die("Banned!"); 
}
```

My overall question, how do I take the fetched data, and put it into an array?

Comment: banning by ip is generally pointless.

Comment: Just an added feature in something I'm trying to make. More of a learning experience to be honest.

Comment: in that case make it chocolate flavoured, a much more useful feature.

Comment: @dagon I will take that into consideration. Thanks for your continued support on my learning here at stackoverflow. I thank you for your chocolate flavored help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`ip2long()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php) function to convert IP addresses to integers. Store these integers in the database and use the following query instead. As GolezTroll notes in the comments, make sure the integer field is `UNSIGNED`.

```
$query = 'SELECT id, ip FROM banned WHERE ip = ';
$query .= ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$query .= ' LIMIT 1';
```

This way your `banned` table is very friendly to indexing, and you're only ever going to retrieve one entry from the table *at most*. Your current code will get every entry, every time, putting a fair amount of load on both your web and mysql servers.

Also, you can probably get rid of the `id` column from your banned table since the `ip` column should function as the primary key just fine on its own.

Comment: A 15 character field can be indexed pretty good as well. I would like using ip2long as well, but the way you do it, the query isn't parameterized. Note that if you do pass IP addresses by parameters, you must pass it as string, even if the field itself is an integer. MySQL integer parameters are signed 32 bits. That means trouble for IP addresses starting with 128 or higher.

Comment: @GolezTrol but a 4-byte int will be indexed far more efficiently than a 15-byte string.

Comment: How then after can I convert this into an array?

Comment: @Necro.: Remove the `WHERE` clause. If you want to display the banlist, `long2ip()` allows you to turn everything back to how it was. Also, @Sammitch is bang on the money, a 4byte int is significantly better for indices, especially if your banlist is long.

Comment: @Necro. `fetchAll()` returns an array. Although with this query all you need to check is if it returned a non-zero number of rows.

Comment: Indexing is better for 4 byte integers, but make sure not to mess up signed and unsigned, because IP addresses will use every bit of that byte. Note that IPaddresses are unsigned, while MySQL integer parameters are signed. It can be done (I have, because I prefer ints as well), but keep in mind that there are a couple of things to take care about.

Comment: @Sammitch How would I check if it returned nothing?

Comment: Well, you have `$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();`, so `count($rows);`

Answer (score 0):

Don't. It's a waste to query all those addresses into an array. Just use a query like this:

```
SELECT 
  CASE WHEN EXISTS
    (SELECT 
      'x' 
    FROM 
      banned 
    WHERE 
      ip = :ip) THEN
    'Y'
  ELSE
    'N'
  END AS IsBanned
```

Of course you have to fill in the right IP address for :IP. 
This query always returns exactly 1 record. That record always contains either 'Y' if the IP address is banned or 'N' if it is not. 
The query keeps working, even if you accidentally ban an IP twice, although I would prevent that by adding a unique constraint (unique index) on that field.

Note however, that banning by IP isn't ideal. Many people still have a different IP address each day. That means that they can still reach your site, while an innocent other can't. Also, entire households and companies use the same IP, so blocking 1 user, can block an entire company of thousands.

IP addresses (IPv4, that is) can be stored in an integer field. Note however, that if you pass IP addresses by parameters, you must pass it as a string, even if the field itself is an integer. MySQL integer parameters are signed 32 bits. That means trouble for IP addresses starting with 128 or higher. It will mess up your comparison.